# How to change my .vb code from auto generate keys to manual input

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to programming , got very limited knowledge. Just want to make a small application to save employee details using vb.net. With the help of my frnds done some part of programming. But the code I'm using is generating the Ids automatically. I want to type in the Employee Id malually. Please help...

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Public Class frmEmployee_registration
Dim rdr As oledbDataReader = Nothing
Dim dtable As New DataTable
Dim con As oledbConnection = Nothing
Dim adp As oledbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim cmd As oledbCommand = Nothing
Dim dt As New DataTable

Dim cs As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ManagerDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Private Sub Employee_registration_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    frmMainMenu.Show()
End Sub
Public Sub AutoGenerate()
    EmployeeID.Text = "AL-" & GetUniqueKey(4)
End Sub
Public Shared Function GetUniqueKey(ByVal maxSize As Integer) As String
    Dim chars As Char() = New Char(61) {}
    chars = "123456789".ToCharArray()
    Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(0) {}
    Dim crypto As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data)
    data = New Byte(maxSize - 1) {}
    crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data)
    Dim result As New StringBuilder(maxSize)
    For Each b As Byte In data
        result.Append(chars(b Mod (chars.Length)))
    Next
    Return result.ToString()
End Function
Sub Reset()
    EmployeeID.Text = ""
    EmployeeName.Text = ""
    Address.Text = ""
    MobileNo.Text = ""
    Email.Text = ""
    Designation.Text = ""
    Department.Text = ""
    DateOfJoining.Text = Today
    Salary.Text = ""
    BloodGroup.Text = ""
    BasicWorkingTime.Text = ""
    Update_Record.Enabled = False
    Delete.Enabled = False
    Save.Enabled = True
    EmployeeName.Focus()
End Sub


Private Sub NewRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewRecord.Click
    Reset()
End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click

    If Len(Trim(EmployeeName.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter employee name", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        EmployeeName.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(Address.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter address", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Address.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(MobileNo.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter mobile no.", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        MobileNo.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(Department.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter department", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Department.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(Designation.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter designation", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Designation.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(Salary.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter basic Salary", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Salary.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(BasicWorkingTime.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter basic working time", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        BasicWorkingTime.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Try
        AutoGenerate()
            con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
            con.Open()

            Dim cb As String = "insert into employeeregistration(employeeid,employeename,address,mobileno,email,bloodgroup,department,designation,dateofjoining,salary,basicworkingtime) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11)"

            cmd = New oledbCommand(cb)

            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d1", oledbType.Varchar, 30, "employeeid"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d2", oledbType.VarChar, 100, "employeename"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d3", oledbType.VarChar, 200, "address"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d4", oledbType.Varchar, 10, "mobileno"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d5", oledbType.Varchar, 60, "email"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d6", oledbType.Varchar, 10, "bloodgroup"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d7", oledbType.Varchar, 60, "department"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d8", oledbType.Varchar, 60, "designation"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d9", oledbType.Varchar, 30, "dateofjoining"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d10", oledbType.Varchar, 10, "salary"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New oledbParameter("@d11", oledbType.Varchar, 10, "basicworkingtime"))

            cmd.Parameters("@d1").Value = EmployeeID.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d2").Value = EmployeeName.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d3").Value = Address.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d4").Value = MobileNo.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d5").Value = Email.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@d6").Value = BloodGroup.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d7").Value = Department.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d8").Value = Designation.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d9").Value = DateOfJoining.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d10").Value = Salary.Text


            cmd.Parameters("@d11").Value = BasicWorkingTime.Text
            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Employee Profile", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Save.Enabled = False
            Filldepartment()
            FillDesignation()

            EmployeeID.Focus()

            con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Just remove AutoGenerate() function and put a validation on EmployeeID. Of course you have to add some validation for unique id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Just remove AutoGenerate() function in order to add id manually as you said. As for the validation, check EmployeeID.Text Is Not "" and also before insert sql do a select count(*) from yourtable. If there is a record with the inserted id just to an update or nothing.

Comment: I have removed Auto Generate and added validation for Employee ID. But it is not allowing me to enter manually.

Comment: Check if EmployeeID is disable or readonly.